# Stress-energy tensor and hair

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I recently read this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9601020) which discusses about a line element of a black hole with some stress-energy tensor with density and pressures. Also there are more similar [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14512) as well.

I don't understand if the $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the stress tensor of the spacetime (that is zero for example in the Schwarzschild case), or is it the stress tensor of the scalar hair?

It seems that if we take $T_{\mu\nu}=0$ the discussion is mute, but, the final result can be referred to the photosphere of the Schwarzschild BH.

Comment: The link for the first paper does not work.

Comment: I changed it now to the arxiv link, thanks

Comment: They explicitly mention throughout the presence of matter fields

Comment: So, for example, if I want to apply their paper to the Schwarzschild metric, the stress-energy tensor is totally that of the scalar field?
On the other hand, if so, Einsteins equations doesn't add up since the Schwarzschild  metric is a solution for the vacuum